# nodejs merge array

Tags: json, node.js, geoip

Im doint some nodejs fiddling with blogposts from wordpress and geotagging of theese posts. I have integrated geolite into nodejs and from wordpress i get the client id. Here is what my nodejs code looks like for now.

```
native.on('data',
  function(data)
  {
    //console.log(data)
    listener.sockets.emit('notification', data);
    jsonstring = JSON.parse(data)
    var ip = jsonstring.clientip
    var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
    console.log(ip);
    console.log(geo);
    listener.sockets.emit('geodata', geo);
  }
);
```

As you can see the lat / long is sent seperate from the json encoded data to the socket.

I want to merge the lat / long into "data" and sent is as 1 object. I cant figure out how to do this. i Hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expando/ad-hoc property or two should suffice:

```
listener.sockets.emit('notification', data);
jsonstring = JSON.parse(data)
var ip = jsonstring.clientip
var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
jsonstring.geo = geo;
// or
jsonstring.lat = geo.lat;
jsonstring.lng = geo.lng;
```

Comment: this seems to work, but i need to encode the "jsonstring" into json again before sending it to the socket. How do i do json encoding after adding the data to the array ?

Comment: I ended up with this solution that works.. thx for helping out :-)

    native.on('data',
      function(data)
      {
        jsonstring = JSON.parse(data)
        var ip = jsonstring.clientip
        var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
        jsonstring.lat = geo.ll[0];
        jsonstring.lng = geo.ll[1];
        jsondata = JSON.stringify(jsonstring);
        listener.sockets.emit('notification', jsondata);
console.log(jsondata);
     }
    );
    native.on('end',
      function() {
        }
    );
}

Answer (score 0):

Add the `geo` information as another property of your parsed data object before emitting it:

```
native.on('data',
  function(data)
  {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data)
    obj.geo = geoip.lookup(obj.ip);
    listener.sockets.emit('notification', JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
    listener.sockets.emit('notification', data);
    jsonstring = JSON.parse(data)
    var ip = jsonstring.clientip
    var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
    jsonstring['geo'] = geo;
```

to append the data in jsonstring

[ ] will be more helpful when we have dynamic key values